# Azure > Application Settings > App Setting NOT setting process.env.My_Custom_Variable

Tags: node.js, azure, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

I deployed a react app to Azure, but the process.env is not the same as what I set in the Azure Portal > Application Settings. I'm using CICD in VSTS by the way. Locally I'm using a .env file and it works fine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest isolating to get down to the essential. e.g. CICD seems irrelevant, and so does react. If so, leave them out. Try a trivial Hello World node app, and see if you're able to to get some FOO app setting.

Comment: CICD in VSTS is not that irrelevant, because I saw I can also set my environment variables in the Release phase. Tried, but didn't work.

Comment: It's not relevant if you've already established that the App Setting shows up correctly in the portal.